# Margin when flex wraps

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following situation using flex: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/eduardodeasousa/pen/rNzLrmV)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.first-card {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 480px;
  padding: 24px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}

.content {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  grid-gap: 32px;
  display:flex;
}

.left-content {
  border: 1px green solid;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 200px;
}

.right-content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px deeppink solid;
  flex-basis: 200px;
}

</style>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="first-card">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="left-content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam ab assumenda ex sint esse atque consectetur in velit voluptate quibusdam beatae quam vero a natus, id recusandae laudantium sed, incidunt rem? Dolores eveniet beatae asperiores repellendus veniam hic accusantium qui, totam non fuga earum nobis architecto. Et rem alias tempore.
        </div>
        <div class="right-content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor, consequuntur omnis doloremque nostrum aliquam minima facere, modi possimus quo atque velit eum pariatur assumenda, quisquam laborum officiis at! Ut libero accusamus delectus dignissimos vitae reiciendis quasi tempora labore culpa doloremque ullam, vero, enim repellat qui nihil quaerat? Reiciendis, aspernatur quo?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button> My button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want that when the div is smaller than 490px (it wraps) that a margin exists between "My button" and the last item in "content", which would be "right content" from the example.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this with content `margin-bottom:clamp(0px,(450px - 100%)*9999,20px)`. It's a conditional margin based on the value `450px`. If the container is bigger than `450px` you have `0px` else you have `20px`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.first-card {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 480px;
  padding: 24px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow:auto;
  resize:horizontal;
}

.content {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  grid-gap: 32px;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom:clamp(0px,(450px - 100%)*9999,20px)
}

.left-content {
  border: 1px green solid;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 200px;
}

.right-content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px deeppink solid;
  flex-basis: 200px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="first-card">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="left-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam ab assumenda ex sint esse atque consectetur in velit voluptate quibusdam beatae quam vero a natus, id recusandae laudantium sed, incidunt rem? Dolores eveniet beatae asperiores repellendus
        veniam hic accusantium qui, totam non fuga earum nobis architecto. Et rem alias tempore.
      </div>
      <div class="right-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor, consequuntur omnis doloremque nostrum aliquam minima facere, modi possimus quo atque velit eum pariatur assumenda, quisquam laborum officiis at! Ut libero accusamus delectus dignissimos vitae
        reiciendis quasi tempora labore culpa doloremque ullam, vero, enim repellat qui nihil quaerat? Reiciendis, aspernatur quo?
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button> My button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No waaaay you managed this way, ahahha. Would you mind to explain me why (450px -100%) * 9999 ? I got the 450px part, but the -100% and *9999 I didnt.

Comment: @EduardoSousa 100% is the width of the parent element so it's 450px - width of parent. the 9999 is to make sure we always get a big value (either negative or positive) to avoid falling into the range [0 20]. This will make sure we always have bigger than 20px (so clamped to 20px) or smaller than 0 (so clamped to 0)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately with just CSS, no. If your div width relies on something like screen width, you could use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

With javascript, You could poll the element for its width and conditionally add or remove the styling needed for the buttons `margin-top`.